# Vue v-carousel only working for first instance

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have multiple cards on a page, each has a dialog box which opens to show a carousel of images relating to that card.

The images show the first time I open a dialog box but then wont for any following.  If I go back to the initial one where the images were showing they're now not.

There are no errors or warnings in the console.

```html
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="80vw">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn class="btn-info" v-on="on">More Info &rarr;</v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title>{{project.name}}</v-card-title>

        <v-carousel >
          <v-carousel-item v-for="(image, index) in project.images" :key="image.id" :src="image.src"></v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="primary" flat @click="dialog=false">Close</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

I can't see anything in the documentation about how to handle multiple carousels on a page.  Should they have specific keys?

Answer (score 0):

Is project.images a directory you're trying to use? It's kind of hard to figure out the issue without the script section and what you data or props section looks like.

Comment: Project is an object with a property of images which is an array of image urls

Comment: I've since found the npm vue-carousel package which doesn't have this problem so I'll use that instead.

Comment: is each image url in an object with an 'src' key with the url as the value?